# How to fix otfinfo?

Tags: fonts, errors

I am trying to get some information about my fonts using otfinfo (came with Tex Live distribution) and the command line (cmd) in Windows 10. Tried many times with many different fonts (for sure in my system) and different inputs but always get the same error as you can see below in the picture. Seems like otfinfo cannot locate the fonts? Any suggestions how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: I think the font file must in the folder.

Comment: Which folder? All the fonts I tried are located in fonts folder of TexLive.

Comment: which folder you run the command?

Comment: try to run the command in the folder where the font file located.

Comment: I didn't  choose any folder. I just run the command.

Comment: That's mean you run the command in C:\user\Miltos P....

Comment: Thank you Tom. That's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be in the actual folder of the font to use `otfinfo` directly. The prompt shouldn't show `C:\Users\Miltos ...` but `C:\texlive\2022 ...`

Alternatively  you can (with texlive) do e.g. this for fonts that can be found with kpsewhich:

```
for /F %i in ('kpsewhich XCharter-Roman.otf') do otfinfo -s %i
```

This then reports

```
otfinfo -s c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xcharter/XCharter-Roman.otf
DFLT            Default
copt            Coptic
cyrl            Cyrillic
cyrl.MKD        Cyrillic/Macedonian
cyrl.SRB        Cyrillic/Serbian
grek            Greek
hani            CJK Ideographic
latn            Latin
latn.AZE        Latin/Azeri
latn.NLD        Latin/Dutch
latn.TRK        Latin/Turkish
latn.VIT        Latin/Vietnamese
sgnw            <unknown script>
thai            Thai
```

Comment: The first suggestion does not work and the cmd shows after cd command: C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public> .The second suggestion yes it works and thank you for the help. Shall I use a shorter or longer path for fonts folder?

Comment: you really must switch into the folder of the font, not only into some parent folder like the public folder.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! Now it is clear how it works. Now I have the answer I was looking for.